# cudaprof in CUDA 5.0 and how to use it on linux system

Tags: cuda, profiler

I wanted to run the profiler on my code. I have CUDA 5.0 installed and have CentOS 6.0 as my operating system. Firstly, I could not find cudaprof anywhere on my system. I searched on internet and came to know that nvprof can be used to profile from command line. So, I compiled my code using -g and -G options and ran it using the command:

```
nvprof -o profileOutput -s ./exe args.
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error'
  what():  unspecified launch failure
======== Warning: Application received signal 6
======== Error: failed to read result file
```

I am not understanding what wrong am I doing.

Also, What is the location of cudaprof on Linux system with CUDA 5.0 installed?

Comment: Don't compile your code with debugging flags - it is causing thrust to break and your GPU code isn't running

Comment: So can I use nvprof without debugging flags?

Comment: Ok I got it. I compiled without the debugging flags and it is working now :). Thank you

Comment: What is the location of cudaprof on Linux system with CUDA 5.0 installed?

Comment: Sometime back the name of cudaprof was changed to nvvp standing for Nvidia Visual profiler.

Comment: For profiling it is useful to add the option -lineinfo or --generate-line-info to your release compiles. This will generate line table information but not affect optimizations.